# using input argument in attribute (Asp Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i have this attribute :

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AllowAccessAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IDomainUnitOfWork unitofwork;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
    private readonly string _name;

    public AllowAccessAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;

    }
    public string Name => _name;
    public AllowAccessAttribute(IDomainUnitOfWork unitofwork, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        this.unitofwork = unitofwork;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var userId = httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();
        var access = string.Format("{0}:{1}", controller, action);
        if (unitofwork.UserRepository.AccessLevelRepository.ValidateAccess(userId, access) == false)
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
    }
}
```

and i call this attribute on top of my action by this way:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AllowAccessAttribute))]
```

but i have problem . i need pass argument `Name` to this attribute .

**how can i pass argument ???**

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your attribute like this :

```
[AllowAccess("name")]
```